Route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page
It should navigate to "http://localhost:3001/auth/sign-in" route, whenever "/auth/sign-in" or "/auth/sign-in" routes are not matched. Is there any way to solve this problem?
<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Route path="auth" element={<AuthContainer />}>
            <Route
              path="sign-in"
              element={<SignInForm onLoadUser={loadUser} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="sign-up"
              element={<SignUpForm onLoadUser={loadUser} />}
            />
          </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/auth/sign-in" replace />} />
      </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>

